# Elastic cloud roles are not mapping correctly to stack roles

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-cloud

Elastic documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-stack-user-org-member.html) says that the organization roles (Admin, Editor, Viewer) should map 1:1 to built-in stack roles (superuser, editor, viewer).

But it looks like this is not happening correctly.
The setup is this:

- There are multiple Azure Elastic instances (Azure Native ISV Service) that fall under the same organization.
- Multiple users are inside the organization.
- No roles, users or role mappings (beside the default ones) are defined at deployment level.
- Users login with Elastic cloud.

## What I expect

If a user has this setup: [image]

It should NOT be able to see data inside any kibana instance, nor should be able to see deployment informations on elastic cloud panel (elasticsearch service console).

If a user has this setup:
[image]

It should be able to see all data in all instances and be able to edit elastic cloud panel.

## What is happening

- User with None role is still able to see data in kibana instance, but cannot see elastic cloud panel.
- User that has been moved to None and then to Admin cannot access elastic cloud configuration nor access kibana anymore.

This is the error that the second user is seeing when trying to access Kibana (login with Elastic Cloud). The user was previously able to login, I just moved his organization role temporarily from Admin to None then to Admin again. [image]

I thought about delay in role updates, but I can't find anything about it on Elastic docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a delay when updating roles. From my understanding it can take up 10/20 minutes